# Jsoup IOException

Tags: jsoup

I'm using Jsoup 1.11.1 on an android device . I need the html code of some web pages. For this I use the following code:

```
          while (page < numberOfPages){

            page++;   


            String currentURL=tree + String.format("subst_%03d.htm", page);


            Document doc = null;
            try {
                doc = Jsoup
                    .connect(currentURL)
                    .header("Authorization", "Basic " + getBase64Login())
                    .get();




            } catch (IOException e1) {
                Log.i("GyWueInetSvc", "Exception while JSoup connect:" + currentURL +" cause:"+e1.getMessage());
                e1.printStackTrace();
                continue;
            }             
....
```

Very often I get this exception in LogCat:

11-09 16:01:08.127: I/GyWueInetSvc(4412): Exception while JSoup connect:--The url is deleted -- cause:Mark has been invalidated.

11-09 16:01:08.128: W/System.err(4412): java.io.IOException: Mark has been invalidated.

11-09 16:01:08.130: W/System.err(4412):     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.reset(BufferedInputStream.java:336)

11-09 16:01:08.131: W/System.err(4412):     at org.jsoup.internal.ConstrainableInputStream.reset(ConstrainableInputStream.java:103)

11-09 16:01:08.136: W/System.err(4412):     at org.jsoup.helper.DataUtil.parseInputStream(DataUtil.java:105)

11-09 16:01:08.137: W/System.err(4412):     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.parse(HttpConnection.java:832)

11-09 16:01:08.137: W/System.err(4412):     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:289)
....

The relation between "run" and "fail" is about 70:30

What can I do to make it more stable ?
Whenever I tested it the web pages are available from my Windows without any problems.

Comment: Try to add the user agent string of your browser to the get request.

Answer (score 2):

I got a hint  and changed the version of Jsoup. A downgrade to Jsoup 1.8.1 solved the problem. There is no need to change any code,

Thankn